# Classical $\sum_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i^2$ are group forms for $n=1,2,4,8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $F$ be a field. Consider quadratic forms $f=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i^2$ with $n=1,2,4,8$. $f$ is a group form if $\{d\in F^\star|\exists x\in F^n, f(x)=d\}$ is a group.

For $F=Q$, it follows from classical theorem that $\{d\in F^\star|\exists x\in F^n, f(x)=d\}$ does form a subgroup of $Q^+$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ In Lam's Introduction to Quadratic Forms Chpt 1, Sec 2, it says for $n=1,2,4,8$, $f$ is a group form for any field. From Wiki, it seems that it should hold for $n=16$ as well. Note that existence is easy by 2 squares. Then the multiplicative closureness follows from application of correponding $n$ square identities. Does one have any even sum of squares identities as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen%27s_eight-square_identity ?

$\textbf{Q':}$ Was there inductive argument of $n$ for such kind of identities?

If that is the case, then I deduce $f$ of the form above is a group form for any even number $n$ and $n=1$.

Comment: Is $x_i \in F$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for confusion. I think I typed the wrong condition and I have wrote down corrected statement.

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum $x_i\in F$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The definition should be if $\{d\in F^\star|\exists x\in F^n, f(x)=d\}=f(F^n-\{0\})-\{0\}$ is a group, then $f$ is called a group form. And the book claims $\sum_{i\leq n}x_i$ with $n=1,2,4,8$ is group form. The only part one needs to check is mutliplicative closureness which requires sum of $n$ squares identities. The invertbility is not hard.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for my sloppiness. I naively thought that should remove the case of degeneracy but it seems I do need to truely remove $0$ which is required by removing $0$ in the image.